# Load Ebay Watch and Ask Buttons

Tags: javascript, pageload

I am working on an Ebay page and am having difficulty getting a simple Ebay watch and Ask a Question buttons to display initially on page load.

Here is a link to an Ebay sample page:

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/You-Are-My-Sunshine-Extra-Large-Metal-Wall-Art-Rustic-Industrial-Yellow-/171662208500?fromMakeTrack=true

If you refresh page the Watch and Ask a Question buttons are visible however.

And below is script which is inserted into sections of the HTML within body. Do I just need to apply this to a window.load event? My tempplate is loaded within an iframe.

```
<script>document.write('<a href="'+ebayAskSellerURL+'">Ask a question</a>');</script>
<script>document.write("<a href='http://cgi1.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?MakeTrack&item=" + ebayItemID + "' title='Add to Watch list' target='_blank'>Add to Watch list!</a>"); </script>
```

Comment: You have to add those manually? eBay doesn't do that for you? I suggest you look at your browser tools, particularly the network tab and the script console: it's possible something is failing to load on first refresh, or a script is getting executed before all its dependencies are loaded, and hopefully you'll get some useful pointers from those. (FWIW your link worked first time for me.)

Answer (score 1):

For the Watch link, you can also use that "MakeTrack" URL as a simple HTML URL without bothering with javascript, and it should work fine.

[This free tool](http://www.watchcount.com/ebay-watch-link.php) builds the watch link dynamically for you (based off the item no. in the referrer), but it's been a few years since I've used it myself, so I'm not sure if it's still active.

Comment: Thanks for this...looks good. Half the problem solved. Just have to upload and fingers crossed. It takes 24hrs to view changes to API I have to submit this with. 

Seems the main issue is the on slower connections is the iframe is isn't picking up the variables from main page. 

Am getting undefined variable errors in console for ebayAskSellerURL variable etc on slower connections etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely related to the eBay first load behavior. On first load eBay will use their internal style elements. On reload it will use whatever you designed.

The workaround is to define all tags with a unique CSS tag. Make sure not to use any class or ID that eBay is using.

Maybe you can try something in that direction:

```
<style>
.myhref a:link {text-decoration: none}
.myhref a:visited {text-decoration: none}
.myhref a:active {text-decoration: none}
.myhref a:hover {text-decoration: underline; color: red;}
</style>

<span class="myhref">
<script>document.write('<a href="'+ebayAskSellerURL+'">Ask a question</a>');</script>
<script>document.write("<a href='http://cgi1.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?MakeTrack&item=" + ebayItemID + "' title='Add to Watch list' target='_blank'>Add to Watch list!</a>"); </script>
</span>
```